# Why is it that in google fonts both Nunito and Nunito Sans have same url and same font name as property?

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-fonts

I need to set Nunito sans as my website font. So I applied that, but only recently I found that it was the slightly curvy twin of Nunito sans - the Nunito that was being applied.
I checked it out and found that in google fonts they ask to embed the same url to call both these fonts - https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@600;700

And to apply them rule is given as font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif; for both.

Its weird as at present it is applying Nunito Sans in my local and Nunito in server.

Any suggestions?

Links to both fonts in google fonts
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito+Sans
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito

Comment: Please add more details to you question (ideally a running snippet). There might be some overriding rule in your css. "Nunito:wght@600;700" and "Nunito+Sans:wght@600;700" clearly return different `@font-face` rules. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/ZEqbBvw)

Comment: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito+Sans/about: _"Nunito is a well balanced sans serif typeface superfamily, with 2 versions: The project began with Nunito, created by Vernon Adams as a rounded terminal sans serif for display typography. Jacques Le Bailly extended it to a full set of weights, and an accompanying regular non-rounded terminal version, Nunito Sans."_ - maybe they just updated the "old" Nunito to actually use the same font resource, so that it benefits from the added weights as well?

Comment: @herrstrietzel, the OP provided links to both Google hosted fonts. That is all you need to go view that they are the same exact font. But also here is a url to the Google font repo bug pointing out 2 minor differences between the two fonts as a bug:  https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/612

Comment: @Leon Francis Shelhamer: I've checked both google font links and can't reproduce this error (neither in Firefox nor Chromium or Webkit). Both font faces are displayed and loaded just as expected. Please see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/ZEqbBvw). The specimen links also render in 2 different styles - as expected. The google fonts UI also generates diefferent URLs. Feel free to elaborate, if you can shed light on this mystery.

Comment: @Leon Francis Shelhamer: besides, the linked bug report describes design inconsistencies and **not a bug retrieving different sub-families** within a font family group. Obviously, there are lot of pitfalls using the google font API – most notably, the annoying **browser sniffing** (especially, when it comes to variable fonts but that's another story). See this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oSne.png) showing both fonts rendering just as expected.