# "Nunito ExtraLight" instead of "Nunito" in Dev tools rendered font info

Tags: fonts, rendering, devtools

Can someone explain me why in this case Chrome renders Nunito ExtraLight which is not defined anywhere?

Source code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
TEXT
```

Chrome DevTools:

[image: Why Nunito ExtraLight?]

I tried this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@500&display=swap');
```

But result was:
**Nunito ExtraLight Medium**

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I don't wanna ExtraLight font.

Comment: You're right it is quite misleading but you can ignore the displayed in dev tools.  

"Nunito ExtraLight" is the font family name as specified in the font file's name records. The reason for this is probably that nunito is a native variable font. The generated intermediate static font versions apparently take the first weight as a family name. So it's rather a compiling bug

Comment: I've found many sites that use the Nunito font and DevTools always show "Nunito" correctly, so the problem must be on my end.

Comment: a lot of these sites might use local copies or older versions of this font. As mentioned before it is negligible since the different font styles/weight are working correctly. You can also reproduce this error in Firefox. The "error" is definitely caused by google's naming conventions when compiling static font intermediates. If it makes you mad you probably find another version of nunito on github (often provided by the creators) or cdn hosted elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Browser usage: font-family name stored in a font file don't matter

As long as a google font css query returns **valid `@font-face` rules** (correctly mapping different styles/weights) – just ignore this matter.

Sure, it is slightly confusing to see rendered font names in dev tools like:

- "Nunito ExtraLight" light
- "Nunito ExtraLight" Regular
- "Nunito ExtraLight" Medium

[image: weight200]
[image: weight800]

where the "intrinsic" font-family name as specified in the woff2/woff/truetype name records also includes a term like "ExtraLight" that should be preserved for style/weight info.

However, it doesn't matter as the browser only cares about a valid `@font-face` rule mapping a specific font file to:

1. a font-family
2. font-style (regular or italic)
3. font-weight (e.g 100–900)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900');
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito'
}

.w200 {
  font-weight: 200
}

.w300 {
  font-weight: 300
}

.w400 {
  font-weight: 400
}

.w500 {
  font-weight: 500
}

.w600 {
  font-weight: 600
}

.w700 {
  font-weight: 700
}

.w800 {
  font-weight: 800
}

.w900 {
  font-weight: 900
}
```

```html
<p class="w200">Hamburgefons</p>
<p class="w300">Hamburgefons</p>
<p class="w400">Hamburgefons</p>
<p class="w500">Hamburgefons</p>
<p class="w600">Hamburgefons</p>
<p class="w700">Hamburgefons</p>
<p class="w800">Hamburgefons</p>
<p class="w900">Hamburgefons</p>
```

### google fonts API requests are dynamic

In other words: the exact same google fonts css URL might return different file sources after e.g. 2 years.
... not to speak of "browser sniffing" – for instance [returning static instead of variable fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70201880/google-fonts-variable-fonts-not-working-in-windows-browsers/70277406#70277406) when using  Opera (maybe the user agent lookup is still based on old presto rendering engine data?)

So you can safely ignore this issue – this might be more significant when employing fonts for native apps.

The Nunito also caused some [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989700/why-is-it-that-in-google-fonts-both-nunito-and-nunito-sans-have-same-url-and-sam) due to its sibling the "Nunito Sans". Both fonts shouldn't be confused.